# Show specific data based on the role of the user

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, administrator, settings

I am making an MVC application and as an Admin I choose what information I should show to the users.

So I have a menu button  to create some categories. Sometimes I want this option to be available to the users sometimes not and based on that I hide it.

When  I dont want the create option to be available, in the view it will be hidden so the users cant see it.But on the bottom of the view  I have a created button which has same function.

How Can I hide this button when my menu button is hidden.

Can I do it in the view somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can give some class to button in view like in menu
 <button class="btnCreateView"></button>

 In Footer 
 Give the same button with other class name
 <button class="btnCreateFooter" style="display:none;"></button>

 Now in the view not footer
 Add this jquery 
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     if( $('.btnCreateView').length > 0 )
     {
        $('.btnCreateFooter').show();
     }
  });
 <script>
```